# Side-by-Side Asp.Net and MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvccontrib

We have an existing ASP.Net Web Application. I would like to create an ASP.Net MVC Razor Application where the two applications will work together. A single Master Page would contain menu items that can call .aspx pages as well as Razor .cshtml pages.

I have seen an example using MvcContrib Portable areas utilizing Routing. This particular example has .aspx pages in both (the MVC was not Razor).

Is there an example out there that will show the two running side-by-side and the MVC is Razor? It would be best if I could download a visual Studio Solution so that I can run this.

I am not sure if the MvcContrib way is the latest and best way to achieve this.

**I do not want to go Hybrid!**

Answer (score 5):

You don't need any other external librarry. You can always convert the existing ASP.NET web forms Project to be a Hybrid one which uses webforms and MVC. You need to add the required MVC  assembly references and make some changes to the web.config and you are all set. Scott has a simple and awesome [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx) about this where he explains how to do the conversion.

I scribbled a note about how to enable the MVC specific Context menu( Add Controller / Add View) in the hybrid project after conversion [here](http://www.techiesweb.net/how-to-get-add-view-add-controller-menus-in-solution-explorer-when-converting-existing-asp-net-web-for-project-to-mvc/)

Comment: I am not wanting to go the Hybrid way.

Comment: If you want to add MVC to existing ASP.NET web form project. That is hybrid